# Making TextMate2 highlight every occurrence of a variable?

Tags: textmate, textmate2

Is there a way to make `TextMate2` highlight every occurrence of a variable when I place the cursor on the variable like in Eclipse?

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly, however it is quite easy to get this selection. Once you have it, TextMate's multiple cursors afford easy refactoring. Lets start by discussing some shortcuts:

`Ctrl` + `s` gives you an "Incremental Search" dialog, reduced to a text bar along the bottom of the window, this far simpler than the `command`+`f` version. Pressing Escape will select the current result.

`Command` + `e` sets search query.

`Option` + `Command` + `f` searches the entire document for your query

So to highlight every instance you could

- Select the string
- `Command` + `e` (set search query)
- `Option` + `Command` + `f` (select all instances in the document)

What is really neat about this is that it creates a selection and cursor on each search result, so:

- If you wanted to refactor you could simply start typing the new variable name.
- The cursors also support multiple selection copying and pasting, and some bundle actions.

Comment: It’s worth mentioning that ⌃W without a selection does “Select Word” but with a selection, it extends the selection to include next occurrence of what is selected.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the ^W method only includes _next_ occurrences.